# how to redirect to post page when payment is done in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

**how can i send back to payment page which is post type**

```
My routes
Route::post('/payment', 'PaymentsController@getPayment')->name('/payment');
Route::post('/charge', 'PaymentsController@payPayment');
```

**My controller**

```
 first method for post requests
public function getPayment(Request $req)
  {
    $csdetails = array(['courseid' => $req['courseid'] , 'coursename' => $req['coursename'], 'courseprice' => $req['courseprice']]);
    //dd($csdetails);
    return view('/payment')->with('csdetails', $csdetails); 
  }
```

second method after select to purchase

```
public function payPayment(Request $request)
  {

    $price=$request->courseprice;
    $this->validate($request, [
            'card_no' => 'required',
            'expiry_month' => 'required',
            'expiry_year' => 'required',
            'cvv' => 'required',
        ]);
      //$stripe = Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));

      $stripe = Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_bCgnRBd3BoVvH6QU3gBPbBkQ');
      try {
            $response = \Stripe\Token::create(array(
                "card" => array(
                    "number"    => $request->input('card_no'),
                    "exp_month" => $request->input('expiry_month'),
                    "exp_year"  => $request->input('expiry_year'),
                    "cvc"       => $request->input('cvv')
                )));
                if (!isset($response['id'])) {
                return redirect()->route('payment');
            }

            $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
                'card' => $response['id'],
                'currency' => 'USD',
                'amount' =>  $price,
                'description' => 'wallet',
            ]);


             if($charge['status'] == 'succeeded') {
```

**here iam getting error of get method because it is getting post type data on payment page**

```
                return redirect('payment')->with('success', 'You Purchased A Courses Successfully!');

            } else {
                return redirect('payment')->with('error', 'something went to wrong.');
            }
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
  }
}
```

**Please help me how to i redirect to payment page whic is post type and save the values in db here**

Comment: You should be using ```Route::get('/payment', 'PaymentsController@getPayment')->name('/payment');```

Comment: but it gets details from last page which contain post form data.. so get method  is secure?

Comment: Instead of using redirect to post method, you need to use laravel action here, means you will need to directly jump to a method of the post route. I think this will help you https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/responses#redirecting-controller-actions here you can pass the data to function directly.

Comment: please post your answer .so it will more clear